# The difference set of two continuous functions is open

Tags: general-topology, continuity

> Let $f,g:X\to Y$ be continuous functions on topological spaces $X,Y$. Then the set $\{f\ne g\}:=\{x\in X:f(x)\ne g(x)\}$ is open.

This statement seems to be true under some mild extra hypotheses on the topological space, but I'd like to know if it is true in general.

Suppose additionally that $Y$ is Hausdorff. Then if $x\in\{f\ne g\}$, there exist disjoint open sets $U,V$ in $Y$ such that $f(x)\in U$ and $g(x)\in Y$, and $f^{-1}(U),g^{-1}(V)$ are open in $X$ by continuity. Thus if $y\in W=f^{-1}(U)\cap g^{-1}(V)$, we have $f(y)\in U, g(y)\in V$ so that $y\in\{f\ne g\}$. Thus $W\subseteq\{f\ne g\}$ and $\{f\ne g\}$ is open.

Is the assumption of $Y$ Hausdorff necessary here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A space $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal $\Delta=\{(x,x):x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times X$ with the product topology. Suppose that $f,g:X\to Y$ are continuous. Define $h:X\to Y\times Y$ by $h(x)=(f(x),g(x))$. Then $h$ is continuous, and $h^{-1}(\Delta)=\{x\in X: f(x)=g(x)\}$, so this is closed if $Y$ is Hausdorff. Now suppose that given any space $X$ and any pair of continuous functions $f,g:X\to Y$, $h^{-1}(\Delta)$ is closed. If we take $X=Y\times Y$ and $f=\pi_1,g=\pi_2$, we get that $h={\rm id}_{Y\times Y}$ so  $\Delta=h^{-1}(\Delta)$ is closed, so $Y$ is Hausdorff.

Comment: Hausdorff-tastic!! +1

Comment: I'm trying to follow along with what you did, but I'm a little confused.  Did you prove the statement **if $f, g: X \to Y$ are continuous, then $\{ f \neq g \}$ is open iff $Y$ is Hausdorff**?

Comment: @user46944 no.  He proved that **$Y$ is Haussdorff iff for every continuous $f,g:X \to Y$, $\{f \neq g\}$ is open.**

Comment: @user46944 I proved that $Y$ is Hausdorff if and only if for *every space* $X$ and *every pair* of continuous functions $f,g:X\to Y$, that set is open.

Comment: How is that different from the statement I wrote? :/

Comment: @user46944 Quantifiers.

Comment: ---> Weak mathematician here <---

Comment: @user46944 for example: in my counterexample, we could have taken the functions to be $f(x) = g(x) = 1$.  Of course, $\{f \neq g\}$ would be open, but we obviously couldn't conclude from this that $Y$ is Hausdorff.  Hence, we need to talk about "every" continuous $f,g$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom So basically I fixed my $f$ and $g$ from the outset, and as you pointed out, the statement doesn't hold if we do that.

Comment: @user46944 yes. Easy mistake to make. You also fixed $X$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro I have removed the discussion. I hope that's OK to you.

Answer (score 2):

At least some sort of separation axiom is necessary.

Take $X = \Bbb R$, $Y = \Bbb R \cup \{0^*\}$, where $0^*$ is a point that is topologically indistinguishable from $0 \in \Bbb R$.  Define $f(x) = x$ and
$$
g(x) = 
\begin{cases}
x & x \neq 0\\
0^* & x = 0
\end{cases}
$$
We have $\{f \neq g\} = \{0\}$, which is not open.

Comment: What do you mean by topologically indistinguishable?  Do you mean for every open set containing $0$, it contains $0^{*}$, and for every open set containing $0^{*}$, it contains $0$?  That's just a guess.

Comment: @user46944 That's exactly right. Perhaps this condition can be relaxed, though.

Comment: Hmm...What if we equip $\Bbb R \cup \{ 0^{*} \}$ with a topology that's $T1$?  Would that somehow make $\{f \neq g \}$ open in your example?  Even in that case, $\{ f \neq g \} = \{0 \}$ by construction of $f$ and $g$.  Maybe $g$ won't be continuous in such a space?  Is $Y = \Bbb R \cup \{ 0^{*} \}$ equipped with the standard topology of $\Bbb R$?

Comment: @user46944 I think you're right.  That being said, I'm having a hard time on saying *exactly* what should hold in order to prevent such a counterexample from existing.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Hausdorffsity is enough! =D

Comment: @PedroTamaroff right, but is Hausdorffitude necessary?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's an iff, see my answer. =)